# Heroku Rake Task Does Not Understand Rand Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, rake

I have a rake task I created and inside it I have the line

```
number = rand(1..10)
```

When I run this on my development machine everything is ok, however, when I run it on Heroku I'm returned an error

```
rake aborted!
can't convert Range into Integer
/app/lib/tasks/sample_data.rake:57:in `rand'
```

I should note that earlier in the rake task I ran `rand(111)` without fail. I have to assume the problem is caused by me setting a start and end point for `rand` to choose from.

So the big questions is, why does Heroku treat `rand` as a range and not as an integer and how do I fix this?

Comment: which version of ruby are you using?

Comment: Ruby Version 1.9.3p286

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Range support in `rand()` was added in Ruby 1.9.3. You're likely running 1.9.2 (the default) on Heroku. You can run 1.9.3 on Heroku by adding `ruby "1.9.3"` to your Gemfile.

- http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Kernel.html#method-i-rand
- http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-rand